# How reference "Craft" js object in jquery scope

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, jquery

I have this function within my `<script>` tags:

```
$('.btn').click(function()
{
    var data = {
        title: "This is a title"
    };

    Craft.postActionRequest('plugin/controller/action', data, function(response) {
    });
});
```

The "Craft" function returns as "TypeError: Craft is undefined". I'm guessing I somehow need to reference the scope to the function but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried adding `_self = this` outside my jquery click function and reference Craft like "_self.Craft" but that didn't do it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this front-end or back-end?

Comment: It's for front-end use

Comment: Oh man I'm so retarded... ofc I can't use it on the front-end. Haha... Mystery solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Craft" javascript global object can only be used in the backend, not on the frontend.