# 404 Error Controller Action From Jquery But Not Url

Tags: controller, javascript, post

I'm able to call my controller action directly from a url in the browser and get the proper response but when I call it from a page with js I get a 404 error. I'm working off the solution found here [Call plugin controller from frontend with ajax](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11867/call-plugin-controller-from-frontend-with-ajax) but I receive the same issue.

My current code looks like:

```
<form id="call-support-form" action="" class="form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="actions/sage-dashboards-module/sagedashboards/do-something">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Support adhérents">
</form>

    $("#call-support-form").submit( function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var data = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/',
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    success: function (response) {
            //  ...
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest)
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
        }
})

});
```

Any ideas on what I've done incorrectly? I've gotten this working on previous projects using CraftCMS but for some reason nothing I try currently is changing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Craft CMS documentation page](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/controllers.html#requesting-your-controller-action) about requesting controller action:

when you send action as parameter, format should be without '/actions':

```
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="plugin-handle/controller/action">
```

and you can directly open that URL directly- with 'actions' at the beginning as default actionTrigger - because:

> By default, Craft makes an actions/ route available for appending any
> valid action path.

so `http://craftsite/actions/plugin-handle/controller/action` can be resolved when open that URL in a browser.